# Mark commit/branch as toxic

Tags: git, version-control

Is there a way to mark single commits/branches as "toxic"?

**Use case:**

- central repository of source code with multiple branches
  (e.g. `master_a`, `master_b`, `development`, `feature_x`, `feature_y`, ...)
- a software state may be marked as buggy (with description) - aka "toxic" -  by some user
  (e.g. because it didn't start)
- the software should stay "toxic" until the specific flag is removed
  (in particular merging a "toxic" branch, should make the resulting branch also "toxic")
- any commit or branch should be able to hold different such flags
- the "toxic" flag should be visible, even after being resolved
  (to avoid branching from an older, toxic state)
- Bonus: the "toxic" flag should only be removable by the detector or specific roles

We sometimes have the case, that an error is only detected after committing to a centrally stored branch (such as `development`, but also `feature_x`).
When this happens, the specific branch should be flaggable as "toxic" and stay that way until stated otherwise.

**possible solution:**

As far as I can see, tags could do the job. But somebody (a commit-hook?) would have to copy the "some weird error"-tag from `HEAD~1` to `HEAD` if there's no "some weird error [resolved]"-tag.

Comment: Two thoughts: You could just rename the branch to include the word "toxic".  If this doesn't get your team's attention, then they should drink more coffee.  And second, you could also consider deleting the branch if it really poses a risk to your development process.

Comment: deleting/moving the branches would definitely get the team's attention. However, I already hear the "How should we fix it, if it's gone?" of dozens team members and would prefer leaving the names as it is. Especially this would complicate the "multiple toxic flags" constraint.